# Node.js script and systemd service to update CloudFlare on IP address change

Tags: javascript, node.js, ip-address

I've created a simple Node script to read the IPv6 addresses of an interface and update a CloudFlare hostname with those addresses. I've designed it so that it can be activated via an [instantiated systemd service](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/instances.html) that [detects when the IP address changes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159641/systemd-restart-service-when-ip-address-changed).

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const os = require('os');
const Cf = require('cloudflare4');
const request = require('request-promise');
const argv = require('yargs')
  .usage('Usage: $0 -c [configuration file]')
  .alias('c', 'config')
  .demandOption(['c'])
  .describe('c', 'path to configuraiton file')
  .alias('i', 'interface')
  .describe('i', 'Override the interface declared in the configuration file')
  .boolean('s')
  .default('s', false)
  .describe('s', 'skip updating of host')
  .help('h')
  .alias('h', 'help')
  .argv;

const config = require(argv.c);
if (argv.i) {
  config.interface = argv.i;
}

const cf = new Cf({
  email: config.email,
  key: config.key,
});

const IPv4 = {
  name: 'IPv4',
  type: 'A',
  locator: getIPv4Address,
};

const IPv6 = {
  name: 'IPv6',
  type: 'AAAA',
  locator: getIPv6Address,
};

updateAddressesByFamily(IPv6);
updateAddressesByFamily(IPv4);

function updateAddressesByFamily(family) {
  const remoteAddressPromise = cf.zoneDNSRecordGetAll(config.zone, {
    type: family.type,
    name: config.name,
  });
  const localAddressPromise = family.locator();
  Promise.all([remoteAddressPromise, localAddressPromise]).then((result) => {
    const [remoteAddresses, localAddresses] = result;
    logAddresses(remoteAddresses.map(a => a.content), `Remote ${family.name} Addresses`);
    logAddresses(localAddresses, `Local ${family.name} Addresses`);

    const staleAddresses = remoteAddresses.filter(address => !localAddresses.includes(address.content));
    logAddresses(staleAddresses.map(a => a.content), `Stale ${family.name} Addresses`);

    const newAddresses = localAddresses.filter(address => !remoteAddresses.map(a => a.content).includes(address));
    logAddresses(newAddresses, `New ${family.name} Addresses`);

    const removalPromises = argv.s ? [] : staleAddresses.map(address => cf.zoneDNSRecordDestroy(config.zone, address.id));

    const additionPromises = argv.s ? [] : newAddresses.map(address => cf.zoneDNSRecordNew(config.zone, {
      type: family.type,
      name: config.name,
      content: address,
      ttl: 1,
    }));

    return Promise.all([...removalPromises, ...additionPromises]);
  }).then(() => {
    console.log(`Successfully updated ${family.name} addresses`);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(`Unable to update ${family.name} addresses: ${error}`);
  });
}

function getIPv4Address() {
  const options = {
    uri: 'https://ipinfo.io/json',
    json: true,
  };
  return request.get(options).then(response => [response.ip]);
}

function getIPv6Address() {
  const networkInterface = os.networkInterfaces()[config.interface];
  if (!networkInterface) return Promise.reject(`Unknown interface ${config.interface}`);
  const addresses = networkInterface.filter(x => x.family === IPv6.name && x.scopeid === 0).map(x => x.address);
  return Promise.resolve(addresses);
}

function logAddresses(addresses, label) {
  if (label) {
    console.log(`${label}: `);
  }
  console.log(`\t${addresses.sort().join(',\n\t')}`);
}
```

Here is the systemd service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Update CloudFlare with latest IP addresses from %I
BindsTo=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/ddns-cloudflare -c /path/to/config.json -i %I

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```